# rebuilding opencv 2.1 debian package

Tags: opencv, package, debian

I'm trying to rebuild the debian package for opencv 2.1,to create a package for armel supporting hard-float.I was following [this guide](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/12/15/howto-to-rebuild-debian-packages/),but when I use the command *debuild -us -uc -aarmel* I get the following error when it's trying to read the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/home/rodrigo/tmp/opencv-2.1.0/CMakeLists.txt:1214:
Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  Instead found unterminated string with text ")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Generate the OpenCVConfig.cmake file for unix
#      installation in CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
".
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

It is giving me an strange error on the end of the file,as if I'm missing a ")" on the end of a function,which is not the case,as you can see on the complete [CMakeLists.txt file](http://pastebin.com/aeNzK4Tr).

I don't have much experience with rebuilding packages from source.Has anyone seen this error before?

Comment: It seems that some " cannot be paired. You may try to narrow down your CMakefile. You may also upgrade your cmake package.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I double checked the CMakefile searching for unpaired ",and even tried to remove all the messages,but the error persists.
I also upgraded my cmake,but it didn't solved it either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be mismatched quote characters. I had been editing the CMakeLists file using textEdit on the Mac and it inserted a right double quotation mark rather than a neutral double quotation mark, which is what was at the other end of the string.

As a result the string had quotes at each end but the quotes didn't match, hence the error.